# How to get the Queue name that NServiceBus pulled the message from

Tags: nservicebus

I can use this code to get the return address.

```
string returnAddress = Bus.CurrentMessageContext.ReturnAddress;
```

But how do i get the "to address" of the message. i.e. the Queue that NServiceBus pulled the message from.

I had a look through the source and it seems Bus.Transport.Address is what i want but there is no get on Transport

Note: I am within the "Handle" method of a message handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be the same address that is in your MsmqTransport configuration section.  You should be able to pull that section and grab the value.

```
String address = Configure.ConfigurationSource.GetConfiguration<MsmqTransportConfig>().InputQueue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems i just get it injected by adding a property

```
public ITransport Transport { get; set; }
```

And then accessing

```
Transport.Address
```

NOTE: turns out that in the latest source there is no property "Address" on ITransport. So this answer is not correct :(

https://nservicebus.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nservicebus/trunk/src/unicastTransport/NServiceBus.Unicast.Transport/ITransport.cs